# Is it possible to upload YouTube shorts via the API?

Tags: youtube

I was looking through the Google API docs and could not find anything on uploading YouTube shorts. Does anybody know of a way?

Answer (score 24):

As of today, it seems that "Shorts" are just plain Youtube videos, because really any Youtube video can be regarded as a "Shorts" video by appending its id to the `shorts` route, even if it's a 24 hours long video, for example this one: `https://www.youtube.com/shorts/4dhIvyskkB0`.

So just upload a video.

However, it seems that the question should better be: What could raise the chances that a Youtube video be "promoted" by Youtube as a "Shorts" video?

To which the answer is: Follow Youtube's guidelines, [provided here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/10059070):

1. Entitle your video with the `#shorts` hashtag (`snippet.title`).
2. Add the `#shorts` hashtag to your description (`snippet.description`).
3. Make it shorter than 60 seconds.

- The `videos` endpoint request body documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource).

Maybe once "Shorts" get out of beta, things would get more strict.

Comment: Thanks for this answer !

Comment: I'm not the one that asked this question !

Comment: @Toodoo, will you reward the bounty?

Comment: Though the bounty would go to the higher answer. Not natural to have to give it manually.

Comment: Do the videos need to be 9:16 aspect ratio to qualify?

Comment: @galipmedia yes, the video needs to be 9:16, I just tried it and it works!

Comment: Keep in mind that if the video is actually short, you will get 200 status code but if you send ID of any long video as shorts/<not-short-video-id>, you will get a 30x redirect to the original link.

Answer (score 0):

I want to give a few updates, based on OfirD's answer, I can't edit the answer directly because there are too many pending edits.

- you don't necessarily need to add the `#shorts` hashtag to (`snippet.title` & `snippet.description`).
- You just need to upload a video with a `9:16` aspect ratio
- Video with less than 60 seconds duration.

Refer to [Upload YouTube Shorts](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/12779649) to learn more details about Shorts.

Hope this helps!